# how to filter by group keys on an already grouped dataframe (grouped_df)

Tags: r, group-by, tidyverse

Do you know how to filter by group keys (or indices) on an already grouped data frame (grouped_df)?

For example:

```
df <- tibble(id1 = sample(1:10, 100, replace = TRUE),
             id2 = sample(1:10, 100, replace = TRUE),
             value = runif(100, 0, 1)) %>%
  arrange(id1, id2)
```

If I want to obtain the rows corresponding to the last 5 groups:

```
df %>%
  mutate(grp_id=paste0(id1, "_", id2)) %>%
  filter(grp_id %in% tail(unique(grp_id), 5)) %>%
  group_by(id1, id2)

df %>%
  group_by(id1, id2) %>%
  mutate(grp_id = group_indices()) %>% 
  ungroup() %>% 
  filter(grp_id %in% tail(unique(grp_id), 5)) %>%
  group_by(id1, id2)
```

Do you know how to write the filter after grouping?

```
df %>%
  group_by(id1, id2) %>%
  xxxxxx ?
```

Comment: I would like to know if there is some way to write the filter after the data frame is grouped.  The real data frame will be recovered (read) from disk already grouped and it has millions of rows. So it would be quicker not having to ungroup and regroup.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If we need to avoid the double `group_by` with `ungroup`, create the  'grp_id', and then use the `%in%` by extracting the whole column (`.$grp_id`)

```
library(dplyr)
df %>%
  group_by(id1, id2) %>%
  mutate(grp_id = group_indices()) %>%
  filter(grp_id %in% tail(unique(.$grp_id), 5))
# A tibble: 12 x 4
# Groups:   id1, id2 [5]
#     id1   id2  value grp_id
#   <int> <int>  <dbl>  <int>
# 1    10     3 0.527      59
# 2    10     5 0.264      60
# 3    10     5 0.569      60
# 4    10     5 0.157      60
# 5    10     6 0.0504     61
# 6    10     6 0.703      61
# 7    10     6 0.109      61
# 8    10     7 0.896      62
# 9    10     9 0.785      63
#10    10     9 0.775      63
#11    10     9 0.940      63
#12    10     9 0.450      63
```